# Meteor.js, Saving document to file

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm trying to save a document into a file but nothing seems to work:

Client:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
updateProjectForm:{
    onSuccess: function(){
        var json = JSON.stringify(thisProject, null, 2);
        console.log('saveUpdatedDoc client')
        Meteor.call('saveUpdatedDoc', thisProject._id, json);

        thisProject = null;
        //FlowRouter.go('/Projects/');
    }
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
saveUpdatedDoc: function(projectDataArray, json){
    console.log(console.log('saveUpdatedDoc server'));
    var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
    var projId = projectDataArray;
    var json = json;
    console.log(projId);
    console.log(json);
    //console.log(fs);
    // fs.writeFile("/files/" + projName, json, function(err) {
    //  if(err) {
    //      return console.log(err);
    //  }
    //  console.log("The file was saved!");
    // });
}
});
```

As you can see right now it is on Meteor.npmRequire('fs'); But i've tried many other methods like Npm.require('fs') and Meteor.require('fs') and getting Meteor exceptions on all of them:

For example: 
on Meteor.npmRequire('fs') i'm gettings TypeError: Meteor.npmRequire is not a function
on Npm.require('fs'); getting ReferenceError: Npm is not defined
on require('fs'); getting Error: Cannot find module 'fs' and if i'm trying to import fs (import fs from 'fs') then all the app crashes on startup.

I have no ideas any more what to do, i only need to save a file so other proccesses not connected to meteor could read the json file and use it but can't do this simple thing even...

packages.js contains:

```
accounts-ui@1.1.9
accounts-password@1.4.0
aldeed:collection2-core
aldeed:autoform
check@1.2.5
dburles:collection-helpers
erasaur:meteor-lodash
fortawesome:fontawesome
fastclick
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
raix:handlebar-helpers
spiderable
stolinski:stylus-multi
zimme:active-route
meteortoys:allthings
meteorhacks:npm
```

I'm really stuck on this... It should be so simple...
10x

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as requiring fs, which is built in to node, so no package installation is required, but it can only happen on the server, as fs isn't avaiable on the client, or if it is, will give an error.

So in a server method, if you have some json being passed you can do it like this:

```
  const fs = require('fs')
  Meteor.methods({
    if (Meteor.isServer)    
      saveMyJson(jsonData) {
        fs.WriteFile('/path/to/file.json',JSON.stringify(jsonData,null,2) , 
          (err) => {
             if (err) throw err;
               console.log('Saved '+outfile);
        });
      }
    })
```

This is ok while prototyping on your desktop, but remember that when you deploy to a docker instance, the file system will be read only, so you won't be able to do this.

Comment: this throws exception of: Cannot find module 'fs' .... so still not working

Comment: You code has serious mistakes, typos as well. It won't even compile.

Comment: Fixed the code. what version of meteor and node are you running? fs is a built in part of node, and afaik has always been there

Comment: `Meteor.methods) {` still won't compile :)